# Unable to set the password in My SQL

Tags: mysql, windows-7, password

I installed wamp in my windows 7 machine. While setting the root password in mysql , I got following error :

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin>mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I am installing mysql first time , so I have not set the password before. I tried to solve the problem using the [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html). I know this link is for linux but I followed the first step and tried to stop mysql. It showed following error :

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin>mysql stop
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

As you can see, it is not allowing me to use any command. I am running the cmd as admin. Can anybody help me to solve this problem please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use the phpmyadmin that is included with wamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAMPserver installs MySQL with a root user without a password.
Just type `mysql -u root -p` and hit enter when asked for password.
Then you can set a new password by typing `mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD`.

Answer (score 0):

Start `phpMyAdmin` from the wampserver icon

Click on `Privileges`

You should then see a `User Overview` page

Click on the `Edit Privileges` icon to the right of the user you want edit.

You should get a page with a page with a `Change Password` panel

Enter a password and Re-type then click Go.

you should then be able to use

```
mysql -u root -p password
```